# Optimise code for a simple monte carlo like simulation

Tags: r, performance, optimization

I run the following code that works but just take ages and I'm sure there is a way to get the same results much faster.

```
runs <- 1000
prediction <- runif(77,0,1)
n< - length(prediction)
df.all <- data.frame(Preds = rep(prediction, runs),
                     simno=rep(1:runs,each=n))

for (x in 1:runs) {
  for (i in 1:length(df.all$Preds)){
    df.all$rand[i] <- sample(1:100,1)
    df.all$Win[i] <- ifelse(df.all$rand[i]<df.all$Preds[i]*100,1,0)
  }
}

df.all% >% group_by(simno) %>% summarise(Wins=sum(Win)) -> output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be vectorise by:

- Performing a single sample operation (not the additional `replace = TRUE` argument.
- Performing a single comparison `>`

You can remove the inner for loop to get

```
for (x in 1:runs) {
  df.all$rand = sample(1:100, size = length(prediction), replace=TRUE)
  df.all$Win = df.all$rand < df.all$Preds*100
}
```

You can then take it one step further and remove that loop

```
df.all$rand = sample(1:100, n = nrow(df.all), replace=TRUE)
df.all$Win = df.all$rand < df.all$Preds*100
```

Comment: You can use a list of data frames instead, and in run number x, you fill df.all[[x]]$rand. At the end of the loop, you could use Reduce(rbind, df.all) to bind them all into one large data frame.